# Zooming in React ThreeJS scene with zoombar and wheel scroll

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am designing a 3D scene by [react-three fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber), and I want to be able to zoom in on the scene via multiple sources (I'm using a zoom Bar and mouse wheel scrolling for zooming now, but other sources may be added in the future like buttons for zoom in and out). To do so, I am using a global state `ZoomAmount` variable which is a DOM element, and in the `onchange` callback of the bar, this variable is changed:

```js
const handleChange = () => {
    setZoomAmount(refZoomBar.current.value)
}
```

then I made a hook for `zoomAmount` state using the [react useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), so I can change `camera.position.z` (changing this makes zoom effect)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    camera.position.z = ZoomAmount
}, [ZoomAmount])
```

The problem is that I want the value of the zoombar to change when I zoom in and out using another input (in this case the mouse wheel scroll,) but when I try to implement this feature in the same way by using hooks, the code enters a loop since these elements are both affected by the same value.

How can I do this without facing this issue?

I have put a running demo of my problem here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zooming-using-multiple-inputs-lub391

I wasn't able to fix this issue but here is what I have tried:
I implemented two hooks
First, a `controls eventlistener` to set the `ZoomAmount` whenever camera changed and second, a hook for zoombar to listen to `ZoomAmount` value change

```js
controls.current?.addEventListener('change', () => {
      ZoomAmount = camera.position.z
    })
```

```js
useEffect(()=>{
refZoomBar.current.value = ZoomAmount
},[ZoomAmount])
```

- the above codes are not included in the Sandbox code since they make the program misbehave

This is where the infinite loop starts since `ZoomAmount` gets changed if the value of `camera.position.z` is changed and then `camera.position.z` gets changed again because it is hooked to `ZoomAmount`.

I also tried using two different states for ZoomAmount but it only makes the loop bigger